# How to constructing Javascript Array with predefined format

Tags: javascript, jquery

**From  AJAX Call i am constructing  this data in my server**

```
{data:[{one:"1",two:"2"},{one:"3",two:"3"}]}
```

**I am able to access this data using 
data.jobs[2].one;**

My question is that , is it possible to construct a similar array inside javascript also 
I mean this way :

```
var data = [{one:1,two:2},{one:3,two:3}];
```

**Please help , thank you very much**

Comment: Remember that arrays start at 0--data[1] is the last element; data[2] would be undefined.

Comment: learn [JSON](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 1):

To access a value using `data.jobs[2].one` you would need a structure like this:

```
var data = {
  jobs:[
    {one:"1",two:"2"},
    {one:"3",two:"3"}
  ]
};
```

Comment: You misunderstood my question , i am sorry for the confusion caused . I would like to dynamically create this var data = {
  jobs:[
    {one:"1",two:"2"},
    {one:"3",two:"3"}
  ]
}; for example , i will get this values from my database so dependng upon for(var i = 0 ; i<data.jobs.length ; i++) , i want to construct this javascript array

Comment: anybody please help , is this possible to do so ??

Comment: @user663724: You would have to provide more details, like what language and platform you are using on the server side, and in what form you have got the data from the database.

Comment: please tell us what output from database u getting and which programming language u useing??

Comment: Thank you Guffa for the response , i am using Java(Servlets ) on server side    StringBuffer jobs = new StringBuffer("{jobs:[");
   while (rs.next()) {
    jobs.append("{one:\"" + rs.getString("one") + "\",two:\""
      + rs.getString("two") + "\"},");
   }
   jobs.setCharAt(jobs.length() - 1, ']');
   jobs.append("}");
This is how i am constructing Response on server side .

Comment: I am getting data in this format inside my servlet Inside the Servlet 
{jobs:[{one:"1",two:"2"},{one:"3",two:"3"}]}

Comment: I have tried this way  for (var i = 0; i < data.jobs.length; i++) {
   jsonDatarav.push({one: data.jobs[i].one, two: data.jobs[i].two});
     }   but its not working . anyhelp ?? please